# Saving information in firebase database from dynamically created Edittext and RadioButtons

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Iam creating the survey app with firebase Realtimedatabase.I have stored questions in database and getting them in application by dynamically creating RadioButtons,Textview and Edittext.
Now I have to save the filled information from users back to firebase database.I searched and get to know to use setTags but couldnt really able to understand after setting tags how to seperate edittext and radio buttons and get them back separately while pushing them to firebase database.What I want is to get the data from each edittext and radiobutton selected and save them back uniquely in firebase database

Here is the code where Iam creating views dynamically and getting data in them

```
    if (getIntent().hasExtra(Constants.ref_no)) {
        surveyRefNo = getIntent().getStringExtra(Constants.ref_no);
    }
    if (getIntent().hasExtra(Constants.refChild)) {
        surveyRefChild = getIntent().getStringExtra(Constants.refChild);
    }

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Constants.content).child(Constants.survey).child(surveyRefNo).child(surveyRefChild);
    System.out.println(databaseReference);
    System.out.println(surveyRefNo);
    linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.survey_question_linearlayout);

    databaseReference.child(Constants.questions).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                System.out.println(ds);

                if (ds.hasChildren() && ds.hasChild("title") && ds.hasChild("type") && ds.hasChild("options")) {

                    for (DataSnapshot option : ds.child("options").getChildren()) {
                        values.add(String.valueOf(option.getValue()));
                        System.out.println(values);
                        System.out.println(values.size());
                    }
                    String user = String.valueOf(ds.child("type").getValue());
                    title = (String) ds.child("title").getValue();
                    switch (Integer.parseInt(user)) {
                        case (1):
                            if (user != null) {
                                addRadioButtons();
                                values.clear();
                            }
                            break;
                        case (2):
                            if (user != null) {
                                questionView();
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            Toast.makeText(GetSurveys.this, "Sorry!!! Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else if (ds.hasChildren() && ds.hasChild("title") && ds.hasChild("type")) {
                    String user = String.valueOf(ds.child("type").getValue());
                    title = (String) ds.child("title").getValue();
                    switch (Integer.parseInt(user)) {

                        case (1):
                            if (user != null) {
                                addRadioButtons();
                            }
                            break;
                        case (2):
                            if (user != null) {
                                questionView();
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            Toast.makeText(GetSurveys.this, "Sorry!!! Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}

public void addRadioButtons() {
    CardView cardView = new CardView(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams cardParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    cardParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
    cardView.setLayoutParams(cardParams);
    cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f8f8ff"));
    LinearLayout cardLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    cardLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    cardView.addView(cardLayout);
    linearLayout.addView(cardView);

    TextView radioText = new TextView(this);
    radioText.setText(title);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams textParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    textParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
    radioText.setLayoutParams(textParams);
    cardLayout.addView(radioText);

    RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
    radioGroup.setLayoutParams(params);
    radioGroup.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    for (int index = 0; index < values.size(); index++) {
        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
        radioButton.setId(View.generateViewId());
        radioButton.setText(values.get(index));
        radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
    }
    cardLayout.addView(radioGroup);
}

public void questionView() {
    CardView cardView = new CardView(this);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams cardParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    cardParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
    cardView.setLayoutParams(cardParams);
    cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f8f8ff"));
    LinearLayout cardLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    cardLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    cardView.addView(cardLayout);
    linearLayout.addView(cardView);

    TextView questionText = new TextView(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams textParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    textParams.setMargins(20, 10, 20, 10);
    questionText.setPadding(15, 10, 10, 10);
    questionText.setText(title);
    questionText.setGravity(16);
    questionText.setTextSize(17.0f);
    questionText.setLayoutParams(textParams);
    cardLayout.addView(questionText);
    EditText answerText = new EditText(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams editParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    editParams.setMargins(20, 5, 20, 5);
    answerText.setPadding(15, 10, 10, 10);
    answerText.setHint("Your Answer");
    answerText.setTextSize(17.0f);
    answerText.setLayoutParams(editParams);
    cardLayout.addView(answerText);
}
```

}

Comment: if(view instanceof EditText)
all you have to do is add children in linear layout or what ever layout you want to add.
then get children from that layout and check if its edittext textview or radio button.

Comment: Your question is you are able to dynamically add the views, but cannot process the answers. right?

Comment: @Shantanu yes,Iam getting the survey form correctly from database but coudlnt able to save the answers back to database on submit button

Comment: First of all, you are not using the features of Java that is Object Oriented Programming. Define a class that has your question title, answers in the form of check boxes or checkboxgroup. And add these inside a RecyclerView instead of LinearLayout. Then you will correctly understand which question has been responded and you will be able to store and process the result in some manner

Comment: @AtifAbbAsiIam already getting the view.
 I want get the data from the view and save the answers back to firebase database

Comment: You can do with a LL also, but the correct and healthy practise while having dynamic list content is to use a RecyclerView